# Nuxt dev + docker-compose + nginx proxy manager error

Tags: docker-compose, nuxt.js

i am creating my first nuxtjs app with nginx proxy manager and docker-compose.

```
  ....
  app:
    container_name: app
    command: npm run dev
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '45230:45230'
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app
      - ./frontend/node_modules:/app/node_modules/
```

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.11
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 45230

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=45230
```

This is my Docker-compose.yml + Dockerfile to run the app in development mode.

If i start my app everything works as excepted but every 30-60sec i got this error in chrome dev tool

GET https://dev.domain.de/_loading/sse net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200

[image]

Do you know how i can fix this error? does this error appears because i run nuxt with npm run dev?

Comment: Having the exact same problem, did you find a solution yet?